# How to know when the component is loaded?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When creating a AngularDart component, I can use `ShadowRootAware` and override `onShadowRoot` to be sure that the shadow dom is loaded and ready for manipulation, as described by the docs;

> It is guaranteed that when [onShadowRoot] is invoked, that shadow DOM
>   has been loaded and is ready.

However, if `useShadowDom` is set to false, what alternative do I have that guarantees that the component or its content is loaded and ready to be manipulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach. Even though it says onShadowRoot it's still fired when it should with shadow root disabled. We just tried this last week on v0.12

Comment: Did not work for me yesterday when I tried. It never got called with useShadowDom: false. Which really makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: I just tried it again with angular dart tutorial 5. Had to hack it a little to use angular dart v 0.12 but it works for me still. If I print line in onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) I see it logged for each rating, so every time.   Are you still extending ShadowRootAware?

Comment: You are right, it does get fired even with useShadowDom: false.

Comment: What about implementing `AttachAware`?  What guarantees are there when `attach()` is called?