# Wait for dom ready without useShadowDom

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to wait until my component is fully loaded. The current approach would be to implement the ShadowRootAware interface. However this does not work, if the component disables the use of shadow dom:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'travel-step',
    templateUrl: 'packages/TravelPlanner/travelstep/travel_step_component.html',
    useShadowDom: false,
    publishAs: 'cmp')
class TravelStepComponent extends AttachAware{
```

I need to disable the usage of ShadowDom, because I want to use styles from my parent object (e.g. Bootstrap). Is there another way to wait for the dom to be ready?

I want to reference a file upload input. At the moment (angular v.012) there seems to be no other way to upload a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know when the component is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470496/how-to-know-when-the-component-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ShadowRootAware` interface. For example:

```dart
class NgFreeTree implements ShadowRootAware { 
  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) { ... }
}
```

It should work regardless of `useShadowDom` attribute.

Comment: I will get the error type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'ShadowRoot' of 'shadowRoot'.

Comment: The error above is an error with the dart editor launching the app.  We started to see this also, we are trying to work with the dart/angular team to identify where the bug exists to fix.

If you run `pub serve` outside of dart editor (from the command line), this answer is correct and onShadowRoot works appropriately.

Comment: I think it might be type checking that causes the issue. When you run pub serve, I believe, type checking is not enabled. If you run from Dart Editor, type checking is enabled by default (I believe)

Answer (score -1):

It does not give you the error message if you use the following signature:

```
void onShadowRoot(Node n) {
    HtmlElement element = n;
    ...
}
```