# How to select polymer dart custom elements in a angular dart view

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

So, I'm trying to select a polymer custom element(using paper_elements) in my view with querySelector. I'm able to select regular html elements just fine. In particular, I'm trying to select a specific paper-input element. I want to be able to query it's input element which is buried in it's second shadowroot.

I've tried the following:

```
querySelector('#my-paper-input::shadow #input')
querySelector('paper-input::shadow input')
```

and a bunch of other variations. However, no matter what I do, the query always returns null. It's driving me mad because I can style it in css. What do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to use several steps

```dart
querySelector('#my-paper-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
```

but you should also be able to access the value using the attribute of the outer element like

```dart
querySelector('#my-paper-input').attributes['value'] or
querySelector('#my-paper-input').attributes['inputValue']
```

you could also use http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_node_bind
but I wasn't able using Angular with paper-elements recently (see https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1227)

Comment: No dice, I cannot even select the paper-input. >.> I'm trying to run the querySelector in the controller for the view

Comment: When you add an constructor parameter of type `Element` you get the view element passed in then you can call `querySelector` on the View. If the view is a normal Angular component it itself has a shadowDOM. The view component needs to implement ShadowRootAware do your query inside the `onShadowRoot` method. This is when the component is fully initialized. You also have to ensure that Polymer is fully initialized otherwise the shadowRoot won't be accessible.

Comment: Thanks, can I see an example?

Comment: What about you posting more code and I fix what I thing should be changed? ;-)  I forgot to post this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550516 (ShadowRootAware). Here is my attempt to use paper-elements and Polymer.dart https://github.com/zoechi/so_question_24723315

Comment: I've created a [repo](https://github.com/windlessuser/so-question-24788402) with the relevant parts of my code. There are quite a few issues. You can ignore the commute Map class for now it's being reworked to be more angular like. My main concern is the commute controller class. That's where I want to be able to query polymer elements. Also when compiled to js, the ng-view doesn't work. Thanks much!

Comment: I was already midnight here and I went to bed ...
I tried to run your example but I run again into this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1227 and I'm therefore not able to launch your app. It seems you didn't have this problem. What Dart version are you using and on what OS?
I made two comments in your repo but they don't apply here. Your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies contain the deprecated `shadow_dom` package but you haven't included the script in your `index.html` anyway. Otherwise your initialization code looks fine (I got warnings though in `main.dart` line 24 and 25

Comment: I'm on Elementary OS. I've been switching between Dart 1.5.3 Stable and 1.6.0-dev, both are giving me the same problem. I can't query the paper-input element and ng-view wont work run under pub serve even though it works in dartium.

Comment: I can't help you because I can't reproduce your problem because I run into another problem before I reach the state where your problem occurs.

Comment: It works in dartium, but not when you compile it to js. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I can't launch it even in Dartium.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724848/debuging-angular-and-polymer-dart) solved my problem not being able to launch your app. I'll add feedback when I know more.